# Help with understanding the quotient group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ and its members.

Tags: group-theory

In the original question, I'm asked to prove that the quotient group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ is torsion-free.

According to the book that this question is from the definition of the torsion-free group is: "An abelian group where all its members except the identity element have infinite order is called torsion-free group."

So the obvious strategy for the proof is showing that all members have infinite order or assuming that this group have an element with finite order and getting a contradiction.

But I have trouble understating what this group "looks" like and what its members are like.

Is there some visual representation of this group or relatively simple description that will help me understand this quotient group?

Comment: Write up what it means for an element to have finite order (remember that the group is written additively). Then write up what this means for a representative of that element in the reals.

Comment: I don't think there is any simple visualisation of this group. That's just how math is some times. So I would suggest just sticking to symbolic manipulation for this problem, like Tobias says.

Comment: @Arthur Well, technically it has a very nice description (assuming AC), being isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. But that is probably not much help here.

Comment: What book are you referring to? *(Why do users often omitted this detail?)*

Comment: @Shaun I omitted the name of the book because it is very unlikely it would be useful to someone. Its a course textbook of Israeli open university called "algebraic structures" if translated from Hebrew and was written in 1987 by Avraham Orenshtein. Most of these books are a rough translation UK books recommended for equivalent courses by UK open university. but not this one according to my knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subspace thereof.

*Every* vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ is torsion-free.

By the way (assuming the axiom of choice), $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}\cong\mathbb{R}$, because the two vector spaces have the same dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

**Direct proof**

Suppose $x+\mathbb{Q}$ is torsion. This means that $nx\in\mathbb{Q}$, for some integer $n>0$. Thus $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Interestingly enough, without choice it is consistent that $|\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}|>|\mathbb{R}|$

Comment: @Holo That's fun!

Comment: @Holo without choice you have to be careful about the meaning of $|A|>|B|$, but among the possible meanings, the one you have in mind is probably ($\exists$ injection $B\to A$ and $\nexists$ injection $B\to A$).

Comment: @YCor what I have in mine is $\exists$injection $B\to A$ and $\nexists$ bijective $B\to A$ indeed. Even without choice $<$ has one definition. What happens is that $<^*$(order by surjective) is not equivalent to $<$. But yes, without choice it is consistent that there is injective from $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R/\Bbb Q$ but not bijective, so you divide $\Bbb R$ into more non-empty pieces than $\Bbb R$ itself

Comment: @Holo yes it's the same $<$ as my formulation, by Cantor-Bernstein.